# Pagination-like in jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I try to make systeme like paginate in jquery/ajax. When i push the boutton view more i show the 5 next result

```
<button class="btn" id="showFiveNext">View more</button>
```

But i dont know how do this. Its possible to set in ajax a new clause LIMIT whith offset in my first methode or i have to make a calcul whith a counter for show/hide somes element?

I get my element whit this method

```
function getVideoComment($idVideo)
{
    $q = $this->db->select('*')->from('users_youtube_videos_comment uyvc')
        ->join('users_youtube_videos uyv', 'uyv.users_youtube_videos_id = uyvc.users_youtube_videos_id', 'left')
        ->join('users u', 'u.users_id_nat = uyv.users_youtube_videos_id_user', 'left')
        ->join('users_profils up', 'up.users_profils_id = u.users_id_nat', 'left')
        ->order_by('uyvc.users_youtube_videos_comment_id', 'DESC')
        ->limit('5')
        ->where('uyvc.users_youtube_videos_id', $idVideo)
        ->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

and i count whith this method

```
 function getCountComment($idVideo)
{
   $q = $this->db->select('count(users_youtube_videos_comment.users_youtube_videos_comment_id) AS commentCount')
       ->from('users_youtube_videos_comment')
       ->where('users_youtube_videos_comment.users_youtube_videos_id', $idVideo)
       ->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

I show the result whith this ajax request

```
function getComment(){
        var videoId = '<?php echo $idVideo ?>';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>video/getVideoComment?videoid=" +videoId,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(resGetVideoCom){

                $('#showVideoComm').empty();

                $.each(resGetVideoCom,function(key, value){

                    var avatarUser = '<img class="img-circle" src=" '+value.users_youtube_avatar_channel+' " height="52" alt="avatar user" >';                   
                    var pseudoUser = '<span class="pseudoComment">'+value.users_youtube_pseudo_channel+'</span>';           
                    var commentDate = '<span class="dateComment"> '+value.users_youtube_videos_comment_date+'</span><br>';
                    var commentValue = '<div class="valueComment">'+value.users_youtube_videos_comment_com+'</div><br><br>';

                    $('#showVideoComm').append(

                        avatarUser+
                        pseudoUser+
                        commentDate+
                        commentValue

                    );
                });
            },
            error:function(resGetVideoCom){

            }
        });
    }
```

and the counter

```
function getCountComment(){
        var videoId = '<?php echo $idVideo ?>';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>video/getCountComment?videoid=" +videoId,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(resGetCountComment){
                $('#showCountVideoComm').empty();

                $.each(resGetCountComment,function(key, value){
                    var counterCom = '<span>'+value.commentCount+' commentaires</span>';
                    $('#showCountVideoComm').append(

                        counterCom

                    ).hide().fadeIn("slow");
                });
            },
            error:function(resGetCountComment){

            }
        });
    }
```

thanks for your help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks i get it. I add an hidden input in my function getCountComment() whith value = 5.

When i click on the button "View more", i get the value of this input and i start an ajax request and the LIMIT clause is the value of this input.

On the success of this request, i add '5' in the value of the input.

Every time i click on the button my LIMIT take +5

Its worked but not sure its the good way.